# How do you access a variable from mapStateToProps when rendering a React component as a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that I am trying to access the state from, it looks like this:

```
const Product = ({add, id, title, image}) => (
  <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(id)}>
    <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.productImage}/>
    {title}
  </div>
);

export default connect(() => ({}), {add})(Product);
```

I have added MapStateToProps, and now it looks like this:

```
const Product = ({add, id, title, image}) => (
  <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(id)}>
    <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.productImage}/>
    {title}
    {items.length}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.cart.items,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {add})(Product);
```

With the code above, I get `items is not defined` in my console. Yet when removing `{items.length}` and using React dev tools, I can see that the Product component has access to `items`. How do I read this `items` variable from the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` maps state to `items` prop. It's not a variable but a prop, i.e. `props` property.

It should be accessed from `props`, as any other prop:

```
const Product = ({add, id, title, image, items}) => (
  <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(id)}>
    <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.productImage}/>
    {title}
    {items.length}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This design pattern of destructuring the props parameter this way is very non-standard

```
const Product = ({add, id, title, image}) => (
```

I would advise against it because it makes debugging your code hard. You can't console.log your props parameter to try to debug problems. Also, it would be confusing to anyone reading your code because its not something they would have seen.

```
const Product = (props) => (
   <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(props.id)}>
       <img src={props.image} alt={props.title} className={styles.productImage}/>
       {props.title}
       {props.items.length}
   </div>
);
```

If that doesn't work, something might be wrong in your actions or your reducers. So, you will need start by adding console.logs

```
const Product = (props) => {
   console.log(props)
   return (
       <div className={styles.product} onClick={() => add(props.id)}>
           <img src={props.image} alt={props.title} className={styles.productImage}/>
           {props.title}
          {props.items.length}
       </div>
   )
};
```

And

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
       items: state.cart.items,
    };
};
```

Comment: *This design pattern of destructuring the props parameter this way is very non-standard* - on the contrary, it's very common, this is what param destructuring is for. I agree there are possible implications with debugging destructured params, but *it makes debugging your code hard* is not a true for React app; since it's usually transpiled to ES5, an arrow is transpiled to regular function and `arguments` can be debugged at breakpoint. Without a breakpoint it can be logged as `console.log(eval('arguments'))`.

Comment: I haven't seeing any tutorials or major libraries do it this way. Material-UI, for example, in their docs always destructures the classes property inside of the function body. "function SimpleAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;"

Comment: This is a matter of style. Tutorials may use `props` param for clarity. I encourage the lack of destructured params in ES6 environments because that's where debugging becomes a problem; native arrows cannot be debugged with `arguments`.